# How to disable loops from automatically wrapping non-marked up content?

Tags: templating, craft3, forloop

So I've got a completely clean install of Craft 3: RC 2. I've installed Redactor, and nothing else.

In the templates/index.twig file; this is all I have:

```
{% set test = ['one', 'two', 'three'] %}

{% for t in test %}
  {{ t }}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

[image]

After some trial and error, I figured out that content without any html markup will be wrapped with 'pre' tags by default. Is there an option to stop this behaviour? Maybe a general config option I can disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that's just your browser's console trying to tidy things up when you inspect.

If you View Page Source, I'd guess it wouldn't be there.

I also just tested this with your example code on a fresh Craft 3 install on the latest Chrome and Firefox on Windows and the latest Safari on OSX and was not able to reproduce your picture.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for taking the time to replicate this Brad.

You are quite right. This has nothing to do with Craft 3. **Turns out the [json-viewer](https://github.com/tulios/json-viewer) Chrome extension I have installed was adjusting the markup! Uninstalling it did the trick.**

I've never seen anything do that before. Should I be remove this question from StackExchange?

Thanks again.